# How can I get rid of Xamarin Android build warnings?

Tags: android, xamarin

When building a Xamarin Forms Android app, I get hundreds of warnings like:

> Skipping
>   .Droid.Resource.Dimension.mr_media_route_controller_art_max_height.
>   Please check that your Nuget Package versions are compatible.  I have
>   updated all Android SDKs available as well as nuget packages.

The app will compile, but how can I get rid of the warnings?

Comment: Can you include information about your Android project such as what it's compiling against and targeting? Also include a NuGet packages list of versions.

Comment: Hi, have you tried [this](https://github.com/UXDivers/Grial-UI-Kit-Support/issues/156)?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [this](https://github.com/UXDivers/Grial-UI-Kit-Support/issues/156).

> You should update only Xamarin Forms package in order to not to get issues with Android packages.

Comment: I don't normally update nuget packages other than the Xamarin Forms, Xamarin Forms Maps and a couple of other 3rd party.

Comment: Here's are my packages:

Comment: In my packages.config, there are quite a few packages like - Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable version = 25.4.0.2. There are probably 20 packages similar all targeting 25.4.0.2 monodroid80

Comment: Hi, I have read [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/504) and [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/89661/a-lot-of-warnings-appear-in-a-new-empty-xamarin-forms-xaml-project), is there any way to reproduce your problem?